# How to write while loop more efficiently in python?

Tags: python

I have written a code using while loop. However I have written the code successfully but it is not efficient. Please see the while loop: -

```
struct_type = { 1:'slab', 2:'beam', 3:'column', 4:'footing' }
z = int(input("Enter the structure type as 1-slab,2-beam,3-column,4-footing"))
while (z != 1 and z != 2 and z != 3 and z != 4):
    print("Invalid Structure type")
    z = int(input("Enter only: 1-slab,2-beam,3-column,4-footing"))
print(z)
```

How to write this while loop more efficiently?
For example

```
while (z != [1, 2, 3, 4]):
```

or

```
while (z != range(1:5)):
```

But both these give errors.
please help in writing this while loop more efficiently.

Comment: Did you mean: `while z not in [1,2,3,4]:`?

Answer (score 1):

Just compare to limits:

```
while z < 1 or z > 4:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while z not in range(1, 5)` which is pretty efficient (`in` checks in range objects is O(1)).

You can also do `while z not in struct_type` since `1..4` are keys of `struct_type`. This is also O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `in` clause.

```
while z not in [1,2,3,4]:
```